# ASP.NET Multiply in Datalist

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, datalist

I have a Datalist in my project and it have a two column("Price" and "Quantity")

Price is coming from database.
I am using DropdownList for Quantity.

I wanna multiply these 2 column and get result dynamicly. The important point in here, if i change the quantity, result have to change without page refresh.

How can I do that?
What is the event of datalist for do this?

Thanks.

My Code

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataKeyField="SIRANO" runat="server" 
                        onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand"  >

Price:<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PRICE") %>'></asp:Label>
Quantity:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="48px">
   <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
<b> Total:<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a JavaScript function to set the value.

```
DropDownList1.Attributes["onChange"] = "someJavaScriptFunction();";
DropDownList1.AutoPostBack =False;
```

Refer to [Client side onchange event for dropdown list](http://forums.asp.net/t/1104755.aspx?Client%20side%20select%20onchange%20event%20for%20dropdown%20list%20for%20ASP%20NET%202%200%20)

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off doing this client side with javascript. The easiest way would be with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). An excelent library that make querying and manipulating the DOM very easy.

Start by adding some CSS classes to the elements we are interested in:

```
Price:<asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="price" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PRICE") %>'></asp:Label>
Quantity:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1 CssClass="quantity" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="48px">
   <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
<b> Total:<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"  CssClass="label"></asp:Label></b>
```

[Next add the jquery library to your page](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/). Then add the following in:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >
     /*Wait until the document is loaded*/
     $(document).ready(function () { 

        /*Function to call when drop down with class quantity changes*/
                $(".quantity").change(function(){  

         //Get value from dropdown changed
         var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()); 

         //Get text from sibling element with class price and clean it
         var price = $(this).siblings(".price").html();
         //Clean it
         price = price.replace("$","").replace(",",""); 
         /*Make it a number*/
         price = parseFloat(price);

         var total = price * quantity;

         /*the b tag is the sibling but we want to update the inner element
         with class total*/
         $(this).siblings("b").children(".total").html("$" +  total); 

       });
     }
</script>
```

See the javascript in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjF6c/)

You will also probably want to format the output as currency: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: It s not working how can i catch the problem? I am not getting result.

Comment: Have a look at the error console. I haven't actually tested this one so there could be syntax errors in there some where. If that doesn't work add `console.log` commands at various points to debug the code.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of typos and added a demo.